# How do I find the list of Stored Procedures?

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

Can you help me locate the list of Stored Procedures I created in the database? I can see only functions.

I am only able to see my Stored Procedurs when I run this SQL statement:

```
SELECT proname FROM pg_proc WHERE pronamespace = (SELECT oid FROM pg_namespace WHERE nspname = 'public');
```

The purpose of my question is that I want to edit and modify my Stored Procedures, but it does not appear in the list of functions.

Comment: Have you tried `select * from pg_catalog. pg_proc` ?

Comment: Yes, but I wonder why it does not appear in the Functions List, and I cannot edit it from the GUI.

Comment: What's the value of `pronamespace` for these procedures? What's the `oid` of `pg_namespace` where `nspname` is `'public'`?

Comment: pronamespace =2200
oid = 59384

Answer (score 0):

They are mismatching. Your procedures have a pronamespace of 2200 and they are being matched up with an oid of 59384 and since 2200 differs from 59384 your procedures are being filered out from the result. Try

```
SELECT proname FROM pg_proc WHERE pronamespace = 2200
```

instead